# AntiSamy is allowing An encoded Script alert to get by? How to block?

Tags: java, xss, policy, owasp

I'm using AntiSamy with the available antisamy-1.4.1.xml policy. The policy is working nicely to block most XSS attacked but the following below is not being blocked. Any suggestions on how to block the following below to prevent XSS attacks?

```
1234%27%2Balert%2873918%29%2B%27
```

Thanks

Comment: FYI, this is being passed as a URL attribute to a coldfusion app

Comment: It's not clear how the string 1234'+alert(73918)+' might be useful in an XSS attack unless you're injecting user content back into JS strings served to another page and executed on the client. This doesn't sound like a good idea to me, and you might consider an architecture change if this is the case. If you've found one problem, there'll likely be many others. Take a step back and tell us what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Antisamy is an HTML content filter meant for allowing an untrusted user to input a limited subset of ‘safe’ HTML. It is **not** an all-purpose input filter that can save you from having to think about string escaping and XSS issues.

You should use antisamy only to clean up content that will contain HTML that you wish to output verbatim on a page. Most user input is generally not HTML: when a user types `a<b or c>d`, they should usually get the literal less-than and greater-than characters and not a bold tag. To ensure this happens correctly, you must HTML-escape all text content that gets inserted into your page at the output stage, instead of anything to do with antisamy.

```
1234%27%2Balert%2873918%29%2B%27
```

This looks nothing like a typical HTML injection attack. The only ‘special’ character it contains is an apostrophe, which isn't usually special in HTML, and can't practically be filtered out of input because users do generally need to use apostrophes for writing in English.

If this is causing script injection for your application, you've got bigger problems than anything antisamy can solve. If this is causing your page to pop up an `alert()` dialogue, you are probably using the value unescaped in a JavaScript string literal, for example something like:

```
<a href="..." onclick="callfunc('hello <%= somevar %>');">
```

Putting text content into JavaScript code as a string literal requires another form of escaping; one that turns the `'` character (the `%27` in the URL-encoded input) into a backslash-escaped `\'`, and `\` itself into `\\` (as well as a few other replacements).

The easy way to get values (strings or otherwise) from a server-side scripting language into a JavaScript literal is to use a standard JSON encoder.

However, in the above case, the JavaScript string literal is itself contained inside an HTML attribute, so you would have to HTML-encode *the results of* the JSON encoder. This is a bit ugly; it's best to avoid inline event handler attributes. Use external scripts and `<script>` elements instead, binding events from JS instead of HTML.

Even in a `<script>` block, where you don't generally need to HTML-encode, you have to beware of a string `</script>` (or, generally, anything beginning `</`, which can end the block). To avoid that sequence you should replace the `<` character with something else, eg. `\x3C`. Some JSON encoders may have an option to do this for you to save the trouble.

There are many other places where inserting content into a containing language requires special sorts of encoding. Each has its own rules. You can't avoid the difficulty of string encoding by using a general-purpose input filter. Some “anti-XSS” filters try, but they invariably fail miserably.

Comment: Nice answer. Particularly liked "If this is causing script injection for your application, you've got much bigger problems than anything antisamy can solve." Big +1.

Comment: My web app has a global search that posts to search.cfm?q=SEARCHTERM... What can happen is a user can post the string above which allows JavaScript to trigger... A bad person could create a malicious url that when clicked on a client machine would run JavaScript and allow the malicious person to steal all the client's cookies etc... Any ideas on how to prevent this? I thought Antisamy was the way to go but given it's not HTML I now see how that's not what AntiSamy is for.

Comment: Each context into which you can insert text requires a particular form of escaping. To prevent injection attacks, use the correct form of encoding for that context. For including text in HTML content (the most common case), use HTML-encoding. (There isn't a built-in HTML encoder in classic JSP, but in anything remotely modern, you have the JSTL/EL features like `<c:out>` which will do it.) For including text in a JavaString string literal, use a JSON encoder such as json.org's, or avoid the issue by putting the text in HTML (eg a hidden input's `value`) and reading it from static script.

Comment: @bobince, I'm trying to work with AntiSamy and it's stripping my script tags, even if they are inside code tags. How does stackoverlflow do this stuff? Is there a purpose built general tool for this? I want to have similar functionality to SO, but AntiSamy doesn't seem to be able to provide it. Am I using the tool wrong?

Comment: @Mohamad: Putting `<script>` inside a `<code>` tag (or `<pre>` etc) is still a real script element, still dangerous, and absolutely something that Antisamy should be stripping out. If you want to allow the user to enter the string `<script>` and have it appear on the page literally that string, ie lessthan-s-c-r-i-p-t-greaterthan, then what you need is plain old HTML-escaping function and not something that tries to strip HTML down to ‘safe’ elements.

Comment: StackOverflow works by using its own custom markup language, which converts simple markup like `**x**` to **x** and replaces `<` with the HTML-escaped version. Having a simpler-than-HTML markup language like this is a common strategy and works well for the majority of sites whose users don't really want to be typing actual HTML source.

Comment: ...however! StackOverflow uses a strategy of *also* allowing you to type arbitrary HTML inside your ‘markdown’ posts, within certain limitations (known-good elements and attributes only). This makes the implementation pretty complicated, and I wouldn't recommend it in general. It kind of makes sense for SO where we have an audience who are familiar with HTML, but even here I find it a bit of a questionable approach.

Comment: @bobince, thank you for the response. So, what if I want to implement a policy similar to SO? Running it through an HTML-escaper would ruin all the HTML that I want to keep, i.e. the formatting. Should I encode the HTML, then convert markdown to HTML, then run AntiSamy?

Comment: @bobince, I guess I should be asking... what type of approach should I take if I want to allow my users to format their own content, and be able to publish code snippets... ?

Comment: @Mohamed: You would have to split up the submitted content into simple-markup bits and HTML bits, running your own simple-markup-to-HTML encoder over the simple bits and AntiSamy over the HTML (or AntiSamy over the whole lot when you've finished, if you can be sure your simple-markup language will never generate HTML you wouldn't allow the user to type directly). I wouldn't recommend it: this is complex, and complexity begets bugs.

Comment: Just getting the ‘simple markup’ language right and safe is difficult enough; just about every bbcode-like markup library has ended up with security holes that have resulted in XSS. Mixing that with actual user HTML as well is pretty ambitious, especially if you need to stop things like unmatched tags breaking your page markup. Picking an existing, popular simple-markup language rather than trying to implement it yourself is probably a better bet.

Comment: What approach your users would be more comfortable with is something you might have to ask them, but there are plenty of simple-markup languages that let you type code snippets. SO's approach of taking everything that's indented by a few spaces to be a code block seems to work quite well.

Comment: @bobince, thanks. They use Markdown. Which is the same editor I'm using. The converter takes care of the transformation for me. The issue is running antiSamy afterwards clears out any illegal tags... including snippets

Comment: @Mohamed: Snippets including `<script>` should not appear in the markdown-converted-to-HTML you are producing; it should end up as `&lt;script>`. If you are running AntiSamy over the *input* that comes into your script you are indeed using it wrong. HTML escaping/processing is an output-stage concern, not input.

Comment: @bobince, what I'm doing this this: input comes in from the user. I sanitize with AntiSamy, then I convert the markdown to HTML, then I throw the original markdown (it's already been santized) in one table, and the HTML in another. Is this wrong? I don't sanitize on output. AntiSamy removes all <script> tags, so markdown doesn't have a chance to convert them :/ ... this is so complicated... I wish there was just a standard library that took care of this.

Comment: Do not blanket-‘sanitize’ input, other than simple sanity-checking like removing unwanted control characters. HTML-escaping and formatting is an output-level issue which you cannot usefully do at the input stage. Putting text from one context into another context always requires escaping, and a different type of escaping depending on what that context is—so SQL-escaping when you're building queries out of strings, and HTML-escaping when you're producing HTML from data. There is no possible way to put this in an input-level or other library that will allow you to not think about it.